# Multiple indexes possible using HasColumnAnnotation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

It looks like in Entity Framework 6.1 they added the ability to create table indexes via the new `HasColumnAnnotation` method. I created a few helper extensions to speed up the process:

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static StringPropertyConfiguration HasIndex(this StringPropertyConfiguration config, bool isUnique = false)
    {
        return config.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute() { IsUnique = isUnique }));
    }
    public static StringPropertyConfiguration HasIndex(this StringPropertyConfiguration config, string name, int order = 1, bool isUnique = false)
    {
        return config.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute(name, order) { IsUnique = isUnique }));
    }
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration HasIndex(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration config, bool isUnique = false)
    {
        return config.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute() { IsUnique = isUnique }));
    }
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration HasIndex(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration config, string name, int order = 1, bool isUnique = false)
    {
        return config.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute(name, order) { IsUnique = isUnique }));
    }
}
```

This works fantastic...until I try to create a second index that contains a column already used in another index. Whatever I add last overwrites the original. Does anyone know if it is currently possible to add multiple indexes to the same column via the new `HasColumnAnnotation` available on the `StringPropertyConfiguration` and `PrimitivePropertyConfiguration`?

I can work around this like I always have by manually adding indexes in the Migration scripts, but it would be most excellent to be able to configure this in the `EntityTypeConfiguration` mappings so I can have it all in one spot.

---

After Gerts feedback, this is what I ended up doing:

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static StringPropertyConfiguration HasIndex(this StringPropertyConfiguration config, params IndexAttribute[] indexes)
    {
        return config.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexes));
    }

    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration HasIndex(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration config, params IndexAttribute[] indexes)
    {
        return config.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexes));
    }
}
```

And here is the new usage:

```
Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(65).HasIndex(new IndexAttribute("IX_Countries_Name") { IsUnique = true }, new IndexAttribute("IX_Countries_Published", 2))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because each of your extension methods assign a new annotation to a property and overwrite the previous one. Let me show that by using your methods in an example.

Say we have this (useless) class

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

And apply your index definitions (skipping the part `modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()`):

```
.Property(c => c.ClientId).HasIndex("ClientCompanyIndex");
.Property(c => c.CompanyId).HasIndex("ClientCompanyIndex", 2);
.Property(c => c.ClientId).HasIndex("ClientAddressIndex");
.Property(c => c.AddressId).HasIndex("ClientAddressIndex", 2);
```

Inlining the extension methods (thank God for Resharper) this leads to

```
.Property(c => c.ClientId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ClientCompanyIndex", 1));
.Property(c => c.CompanyId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
     new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ClientCompanyIndex", 2));
.Property(c => c.ClientId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ClientAddressIndex", 1));
.Property(c => c.AddressId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
     new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ClientAddressIndex", 2));
```

This is the same as writing

```
[Index("ClientCompanyIndex", Order = 1)]
public int ClientId { get; set; }
```

and then *replacing* it by

```
[Index("ClientAddressIndex", Order = 1)]
public int ClientId { get; set; }
```

To reproduce the correct annotation...

```
[Index("ClientAddressIndex", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
[Index("ClientCompanyIndex", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
public int ClientId { get; set; }
[Index("ClientCompanyIndex", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
public int CompanyId { get; set; }
[Index("ClientAddressIndex", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
public int AddressId { get; set; }
```

...the configuration of the `ClientId` property should look like

```
.Property(c => c.ClientId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
    new IndexAnnotation(new[]
        {
            new IndexAttribute("ClientCompanyIndex", 1),
            new IndexAttribute("ClientAddressIndex", 1)
        }));
```

Now suddenly creating extension methods is far less appealing. It's hardly worth the effort to create one for this combined annotation. But for single-use columns your methods are an improvement.

Of course it is clear why you're trying this. The current fluent syntax is clunky to say the least. The EF team [knows this perfectly well](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1969) and they're hoping for some contributor to grab this issue soon. Maybe something for you?

Comment: Thank you Gert. I kind of figured that might be what was happening. You last example shows me what I need to do next. I'll probably adjust my helper class to accept `params IndexAttribute[] indexes` so I can pass in multiple indexes per property. New code added to question.

Comment: +1. In your last piece of sample code you have missed the `IsUnique` attribute, it should have been `new IndexAttribute("ClientCompanyIndex", 1) { IsUnique = true }` and `new IndexAttribute("ClientAddressIndex", 1) { IsUnique = true }`.