# What is the best method for Replacement of HasColumnAnnotation() in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, roslyn, asp.net-core-3.1

I have implemented the project of EntityFramework 6 into EntityFramework Core 3.1. In the EF6, we have HasColumnAnnotation() method used as sets an annotation in the model for the database column used to store the property.

**Sample.cs**

```
private void CreateCompositeUnique(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, 
                                      string indexName)
{
    modelBuilder
    .Entity<Web>()
    .Property(x=>x.Url)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute(indexName) { IsUnique = true }));
}
```

[Refactor many HasColumnAnnotation and IndexAnnotation usages in my schema definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283537/refactor-many-hascolumnannotation-and-indexannotation-usages-in-my-schema-defini) --> the link suggested HasIndex() method.But still confused whether its right or not?

and also I have to do migrate the HasColumnAnnotation() into HasIndex() using Roslyn API.

Kindly clarify on transformation and give solution for Roslyn part that how to do it same.

Comment: I believe you want `.Property(x => x.Url).HasIndex().IsUnique()`

Comment: yes,  it was not worked as you mentioned in Core 3.1, want like this => .HasIndex().IsUnique().